# How to detect last state change in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the [firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) and the [stateChanges](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#statechanges) function to detect incoming changes.

In my database I store messages. After subscribing the first time to `stateChanges` the observer is fired for each message, and at the moment I reload the UI after each update. Is there a way to prevent unnecessary UI updates?

```
this.firebaseMessagesObservable$.subscribe((message: any) => {
  this.update(message);
  this.refreshUi();
});
```

Comment: Where are those updates being triggered from ?

Comment: Triggered by the `stateChanges()` observer. Imagine there are 10 state changes, I receive 10 updates. In update X i need to know if its the last update for now

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please edit your question so actually show the minimal code that reproduces the problem you're asking about. It would also help to know what defined "the last one" for you, as Firestore itself doesn't have a definition of that (or at least doesn't allow querying on it).

Comment: If processing al those 10 messages updates the same value, reading that value will always give you last one...right ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? If 10 new messages come in, I have 10 fired events and therefore 10 UI updates